Orientation for groups
I am significantly rewriting this question, as, I hope, I can formulate it now better from a different angle.
Is there such a concept as an orientation for a group? (For some classes of groups?)
Here is the background that leads me to this question. Let $S$ be a closed oriented surface, $\mathbb H^2$ be hyperbolic plane with some orientation chosen, $G$ be the group of its orientation-preserving isometries. It is well-known that there are two connected components of the representation space $R(\pi_1 S, G)$ consisting of discrete and faithful representations. One (after quotienting by conjugation of $G$) corresponds to the hyperbolic structures on $S$ that preserve the orientation, one to the ones that reverse the orientation. Can one distinguish between them in purely group-theoretical terms?
What I want would be to define some concept of orientation for $\pi_1S$ and for $G$, without really relying on $S$ and on $\mathbb H^2$, so that we can say that one of those components is the space of orientation-preserving discrete and faithful representations from $\pi_1S$ to $G$. Is this possible?
I know the cohomological definition of orientation for manifolds, and I know some basics of cohomology of groups, and this feels like a possible way to produce a definition. But I still do not see for now a natural way to do it.

Do you know about Euler class of bundles?

Yes. But that anyway requires appealing a lot to concepts on $S$. I mean, what I want would be, to define some concept of orientation for $\pi_1S$ and some concept of orientation for $G$ so that I can say that the Teichmuller component is the space of orientation-preserving discrete and faithful morphisms from $pi_1S$ to $G$. Is this possible, without relying much on $S$ and on $\mathbb H^2$?

Yes, you can define the Euler number purely algebraically, although it is unnatural.

@MoisheKohan, Thank you a lot for the response. May I please ask a reference?

I will write a more detailed answer later, not sure about a reference, but will try to find one (I think, one of Goldman's papers).

Regarding "abstract" orientation for groups (without reference to representations), the right notion is that of an $n$-dimensional Poincare duality group. For such groups $G$, $H^n(G)\cong \mathbb Z$ and, hence, picking a generator for $H^n(G)$ defines an "orientation" on $G$. You can read more about such groups in Brown's book "Cohomology of groups". But the answer in the context of Teichmuller spaces is more involved, as I said, I will add it later on.

Here is an answer. I will add references later.
Let $G$ denote the group $PSL(2, \mathbb R)$; it is the group of orientation-preserving isometries of hyperbolic plane. The group $G$ is connected and it's fundamental group is infinite cyclic and we have a short exact sequence
$$
1\to \mathbb Z \to \widetilde G \to G\to 1,
$$
where $\widetilde G$ is the universal covering group of $G$; the subgroup $\mathbb Z$ in the sequence is its center. The choice of a generator $t$ of this infinite cyclic subgroup corresponds to a choice of orientation on the circle boundary of the hyperbolic plane, equivalently, orientation on the hyperbolic plane itself.
Now, let $\langle a_1, b_1,...,a_p, b_p| [a_1,b_1]\cdots[a_p,b_p]=1\rangle$ be a presentation of the fundamental group $\pi$ of a compact orientable genus $p$ surface $\Sigma$, where $a_i, b_i$ are "standard" generators. Their choice is consistent with the orientation of the surface. (Each pair of simple curves on $\Sigma$ representing $a_i, b_i$ has positive algebraic intersection number.)
Now, consider a representation
$$
\rho: \pi\to G.
$$
This representation need not lift to a representation $\pi\to \widetilde G$, the obstruction to a lift is the Euler class (equivalently, the Euler number) $e(\rho)$ of the representation. Topologically, this is the Euler class of the associated circle bundle over $\Sigma$ (the circle is the boundary of the hyperbolic plane). But you prefer algebra, so let's stick with that. In order to define $e(\rho)$ algebraically, take elements $\alpha_i, \beta_i\in \widetilde G$, $i=1,...,p$ projecting to the elements $\rho(a_i), \rho(b_i), i=1,...,p$. The  choices of such "lifts" are not canonical but it does not matter for what we are about to do (different choices will result in the same element $c(\rho)$). Now, define
$$
c(\rho):=[\alpha_1,\beta_1]\cdots[\alpha_p,\beta_p]\in \widetilde G.  
$$
This product projects to $1\in G$, hence $c(\rho)\in \langle t\rangle$, i.e. there is an integer $n$ such that
$$
c(\rho)=t^n.
$$
This number $n$ is the Euler number $e(\rho)$.
Next, $\rho$ is discrete (i.e. has discrete image) and faithful if and only if $|e(\rho)|=2g-2$. If $e(\rho)=2-2g$ (the Euler characteristic of $\Sigma$) then the orientation $\rho$ is "orientation-preserving", otherwise, $\rho$ is "orientation-reversing."
There is also a definition of $e(\rho)$ in terms of group (co)homology, but I am not sure you have enough background for this discussion. In brief: One takes the pull-back via $\rho$ of a certain element $z$ in $H^2(G^\delta; \mathbb Z)$ and pairs it with an element of $H_2(\pi; \mathbb Z)$ representing the fundamental class of $\Sigma$. The choices of $z$ and the fundamental class correspond to orientations on the hyperbolic plane and the surface $\Sigma$. The result of the pairing is $e(\rho)$.

Thank you very much for your very educative answer. May I ask, what is $\delta$ in the very end of the answer?

@Taras: It means discrete topology.
